# Use this with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, bulma

I just want to use bulma-collapsible. However, the documentation is very poor and the only example I found with React is with a class.
How can I rebuild this code so that I use React hooks and without two classes?  Is there another way to write `this.collapsibles = bulmaCollapsible.attach(".is-collapsible", {` like with Hooks or something ?

I think to rewrite the code inside the componentDidMount, can't something like that be done with a useState ?
Something like
`const [isActive, setisActive] = useState(false);` for example.
And then within the code to change it using the constant.

```
class Collapsibles extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.collapsibles = bulmaCollapsible.attach(".is-collapsible", {
      container: this.refs.collapsibles
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref="collapsibles" id="accordion_first">
        <article className="message">
          <div className="message-header">
            <p>
              Question 1{" "}
              <a href="#collapsible-message-accordion-1" data-action="collapse">
                Collapse/Expand
              </a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            id="collapsible-message-accordion-1"
            className="message-body is-collapsible is-active"
            data-parent="accordion_first"
          >
            <div className="message-body-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.{" "}
              <strong>Pellentesque risus mi</strong>, tempus quis placerat ut,
              porta nec nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus ac ex sit amet fringilla.
              Nullam gravida purus diam, et dictum
              <a>felis venenatis</a> efficitur. Aenean ac{" "}
              <em>eleifend lacus</em>, in mollis lectus. Donec sodales, arcu et
              sollicitudin porttitor, tortor urna tempor ligula, id porttitor mi
              magna a neque. Donec dui urna, vehicula et sem eget, facilisis
              sodales sem.
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article className="message">
          <div className="message-header">
            <p>
              Question 2{" "}
              <a href="#collapsible-message-accordion-2" data-action="collapse">
                Collapse/Expand
              </a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            id="collapsible-message-accordion-2"
            className="message-body is-collapsible"
            data-parent="accordion_first"
          >
            <div className="message-body-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.{" "}
              <strong>Pellentesque risus mi</strong>, tempus quis placerat ut,
              porta nec nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus ac ex sit amet fringilla.
              Nullam gravida purus diam, et dictum
              <a>felis venenatis</a> efficitur. Aenean ac{" "}
              <em>eleifend lacus</em>, in mollis lectus. Donec sodales, arcu et
              sollicitudin porttitor, tortor urna tempor ligula, id porttitor mi
              magna a neque. Donec dui urna, vehicula et sem eget, facilisis
              sodales sem.
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article className="message">
          <div className="message-header">
            <p>
              Question 3{" "}
              <a href="#collapsible-message-accordion-3" data-action="collapse">
                Collapse/Expand
              </a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            id="collapsible-message-accordion-3"
            className="message-body is-collapsible"
            data-parent="accordion_first"
          >
            <div className="message-body-content">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.{" "}
              <strong>Pellentesque risus mi</strong>, tempus quis placerat ut,
              porta nec nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus ac ex sit amet fringilla.
              Nullam gravida purus diam, et dictum
              <a>felis venenatis</a> efficitur. Aenean ac{" "}
              <em>eleifend lacus</em>, in mollis lectus. Donec sodales, arcu et
              sollicitudin porttitor, tortor urna tempor ligula, id porttitor mi
              magna a neque. Donec dui urna, vehicula et sem eget, facilisis
              sodales sem.
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="title is-1">bulmaCollapsible - ReactJS Integration</h1>
      <Collapsibles />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

---

My code snippet

```
function App() {
  // the function logic is missing :/
  return (
    <div>
     <div ref="collapsibles" id="accordion_first">
            <article className="message">
              <div className="message-header">
                <p>
                  Question 1{" "}
                  <a href="#collapsible-message-accordion-1" data-action="collapse">
                    Collapse/Expand
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div
                id="collapsible-message-accordion-1"
                className="message-body is-collapsible is-active"
                data-parent="accordion_first"
              >
                <div className="message-body-content">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.{" "}
                  <strong>Pellentesque risus mi</strong>, tempus quis placerat ut,
                  porta nec nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus ac ex sit amet fringilla.
                  Nullam gravida purus diam, et dictum
                  <a>felis venenatis</a> efficitur. Aenean ac{" "}
                  <em>eleifend lacus</em>, in mollis lectus. Donec sodales, arcu et
                  sollicitudin porttitor, tortor urna tempor ligula, id porttitor mi
                  magna a neque. Donec dui urna, vehicula et sem eget, facilisis
                  sodales sem.
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className="message">
              <div className="message-header">
                <p>
                  Question 2{" "}
                  <a href="#collapsible-message-accordion-2" data-action="collapse">
                    Collapse/Expand
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div
                id="collapsible-message-accordion-2"
                className="message-body is-collapsible"
                data-parent="accordion_first"
              >
                <div className="message-body-content">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.{" "}
                  <strong>Pellentesque risus mi</strong>, tempus quis placerat ut,
                  porta nec nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus ac ex sit amet fringilla.
                  Nullam gravida purus diam, et dictum
                  <a>felis venenatis</a> efficitur. Aenean ac{" "}
                  <em>eleifend lacus</em>, in mollis lectus. Donec sodales, arcu et
                  sollicitudin porttitor, tortor urna tempor ligula, id porttitor mi
                  magna a neque. Donec dui urna, vehicula et sem eget, facilisis
                  sodales sem.
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className="message">
              <div className="message-header">
                <p>
                  Question 3{" "}
                  <a href="#collapsible-message-accordion-3" data-action="collapse">
                    Collapse/Expand
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div
                id="collapsible-message-accordion-3"
                className="message-body is-collapsible"
                data-parent="accordion_first"
              >
                <div className="message-body-content">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.{" "}
                  <strong>Pellentesque risus mi</strong>, tempus quis placerat ut,
                  porta nec nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus ac ex sit amet fringilla.
                  Nullam gravida purus diam, et dictum
                  <a>felis venenatis</a> efficitur. Aenean ac{" "}
                  <em>eleifend lacus</em>, in mollis lectus. Donec sodales, arcu et
                  sollicitudin porttitor, tortor urna tempor ligula, id porttitor mi
                  magna a neque. Donec dui urna, vehicula et sem eget, facilisis
                  sodales sem.
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
    <div/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible equivalent for `componentDidMount` would be using a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array like this:

```js
function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    this.collapsibles = bulmaCollapsible.attach(".is-collapsible", {
      container: this.refs.collapsibles
    });
  }, []);
  
  return <div></div>;
}
```

You can always read more about it in the [react useEffect hooks docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, that equivalent for componentDidMount would be using a useEffect I know.
I meant how to rewrite this code which is inside the useEffect / componentDidMount ? 
I would like to find another solution for this.

Comment: I thought you could write this with a useState

Comment: Btw with `useEffect` `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'refs')`

Answer (score -3):

## Background

[Mr. Hankey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16299001/mr-hankey) wanted to use [`bulmaCollapsible`](https://bulma-collapsible.netlify.app) with React Hooks, because he seems not to like React classes. I dislike classes in general and I only do React hooks, so, just like him, I wanted to use this.

Unfortunately, this is the kind og package where thin documentation seems to there covering for limitations. In fact, their docs seem copy/pasted from Bulma itself.

## `bulmaCollapsible`'s React solution...

... does not work for Hooks, period. Stubborn and huimble, I just wasted a good Thursday around this. And this is why I am pissed at [AntonioGarcía](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8340339/antoniogarc%c3%ada). Try it before you post it, or just refrain from posting!

## Enter Moatez (aka SOLUTION)

[Moatez Bejaoui](https://www.linkedin.com/in/moatez-bejaoui-aba208177/), who was kind enough to accept my connection request just now and exchange some nice words with me, proposes a solution that is so incredibly simple it hurts. You can read it [here](https://medium.com/edonec/build-a-react-collapsible-component-from-scratch-using-react-hooks-typescript-73dfd02c9208).

### Approach

His solution uses a boolean state variable — `isOpen` — to conditionally render whatever we're collapsing. This is brilliant!

### Differences

`bulmaCollapsible` (`bc`)'s approach is way complicated. Granted, they are implementing the "open-one-close-others" exclusive mode, but their collapsing  is achieved by making the height zero. I mean, is `display: none;` no longer a thing?  Just checked and it is!

So, `bc` dances around this height zero and hacks its way back to expanding by assigning to the element's `height` its `scrollHeight` plus "px". And all of this because this is 2003. (Yes, I did this kind of thing back in the 2000s, but there were no SPAs then and AJaX was handcrafted.)

### R.I.P. `bulmaCollapsible`

There is a good hack for `bc`, as far as I'm concerned: `npm uninstall`.

### Fix

The only thing I had to change in that Medium article was on line 6, from:

```js
} from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid";
```

to:

```js
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
```

## How about multiple exclusive collapsible panels?

Like Obama once said, "Yes you can!"

Notice that the initial state comes from the prop `open`:

```js
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(open);

  const handleFilterOpening = () => {
    setIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };
```

So, you can use multiple components like these, with props passed from state variables from the containing component and check each one of these with a `useEffect`, making sure you make all remaining false when one turns true.

And as a final touch of class, this compoennt conditionally renders its `children`, so you can just wrap whatever you want with it and relax.